# Failing to install Pytorch on raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, raspberry-pi4, yolov8

I am currently trying to deploy a Yolo model to raspberry pi
so I am trying to install Ultralytics and torch(which is included in Ultralytics I guess) but it shows an error every time.

[image: the error shows this image]

[image]
the second image is the error I got when I tried to install Ultralytics

also, I tried to install it with the wheel file downloaded directly from pytorch website, but it had the same result.

The spec of my raspberry pi is raspberry pi 4, bullseye, aarch64, and using Python 3.9.2

That virtual environment 'tf' is completely new, and I just installed open-cv.›

Can anyone know how to fix it? It would be really helpful.

Comment: Maybe you need a version of Python other than 3.9.2.  Looks like a version incompatibility.

Comment: do you know which python version would be compatible? I've also tried on 3.7.2 but it falied also

Comment: Have you tried on a device other than Raspberry Pi?  See if the issue is hardware.  https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/wiki/PyTorch-Versions

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/install-pytorch-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Yes, i did tried that website's solution, and i've tried on my macbook M2, python 3.9.11 it didn't have any problem. I've also tried resetting my raspberry pi and tried again and also i have another raspberry pi 4 and also failed on that.

Comment: Sounds like a Raspberry Pi problem.

Comment: At the bottom it says you need `torchvision >= 0.8.1`, did you try upgrading your Torchvision? `pip install --upgrade torchvision`

Comment: If after you update torchvision, `import torchvision; print(torchvision.__version__)` still yields less than 0.8.1, you might have to do as @duffymo recommends and upgrade your Python.

Comment: @BrockBrown I just tried that and reinstall torchvision, first i uninstalled and deleted pip cache
and then 
""pip install torchvision>=0.8.1""
then it shows this Warning and installed 0.1.6 instead
""WARNING: The candidate selected for download or install is a yanked version: 'torchvision' candidate (version 0.1.6 at https://www.piwheels.org/simple/torchvision/torchvision-0.1.6-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=5ec9edf604160b4dcf857a66bd499502173e74d4d7a83bd55b08244f6dacb9d7 (from https://www.piwheels.org/simple/torchvision/))
Reason for being yanked: <none given>""

Comment: @BrockBrown I also tried on 3.10.11 environment. still the same..

Comment: So, i just tried installing ultralytics again to see the dependency log, and now it doesn't say anything about torchvision, but it still saying i need torch>=1.7.0 but i can't install torch neither

Comment: Hmm  I think the only other things I can think of trying are to downgrade your Python (3.8 maybe?) or just use Balenalib's Docker image for raspberry pi, it might behave less erratically. https://hub.docker.com/r/balenalib/raspberry-pi

Comment: Torch installs just fine on your pi configuration. You should first make sure apt-get update and upgrade have been run. Then install with --upgrade your setuptools and pip. Finally just use pip for torch components . No need for extraurl parameter. You'll get latest for aarch64. 2.0.1 I think

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry has no GPU. Install the CPU version.

```
pip install torch torchvision --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu
```

(instead of `cu116`)